# MVC ResultStream only working with link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm creating a barcode using ASP.Net MVC 
The problem is it's working with links. But it needs to work with form values.

**This is my controller :**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Barcode(BarcodeModel B)
    {
        string BarcodeTitle = B.BarkodTitle;
        string BarcodeNumber = B.BarcodeNumber;

        Codec objbar = new Codec();

        Byte[] BarcodeImage = objbar.getBarcodeImage(BarcodeNumber, BarcodeTitle);

        Stream Memory = new MemoryStream(BarcodeImage);

        Memory.Position = 0;

        var Result = new FileStreamResult(Memory, "image/png");
        Result.FileDownloadName = String.Format("{0}.png", BarcodeTitle);

        return Result ;
    }
```

**This is my JavaScript code :**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function BarkodKaydet()
    {
        var BarkodModel = new Object();

        BarkodModel.DeweyCode = document.getElementById('DeweyCode').value;
        BarkodModel.CutterNumber = document.getElementById('CutterNumber').value;
        BarkodModel.Year = document.getElementById('Year').value;
        BarkodModel.Bind = document.getElementById('Bind').value;
        BarkodModel.Copy = document.getElementById('Copy').value;
        BarkodModel.BarcodeTitle = document.getElementById('BarcodeTitle').value;
        BarkodModel.BarcodeNumber = document.getElementById('BarcodeNumber').value;

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "@Url.Action("Barcode")",
            dataType : "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(BarkodModel),
            success: function (data) { console.log(data); },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

But it's not working.

It' just working with link how I'm **changing controller to** ;

```
public ActionResult Barcode(string barcodeNumber, string barcodeText)
{
    Codec objbar = new Codec();

    Byte[] BarkodImage = objbar.getBarcodeImage(barcodeNumber, barcodeTitle);

    Stream Memory = new MemoryStream(BarcodeImage);

    Memory.Position = 0;

    var Result = new FileStreamResult(Memory, "image/png");
    Result.FileDownloadName = String.Format("{0}.png", BarcodeTitle);

    return Result ;
}
```

this and **change view to** ;

```
<img src="/Home/BarcodeImage?barcodeText=Can&barcodeNo=12345" />
```

to this.

When the page opening, the linked image sending values to controller and showing barcode to me.

**But I need**;

When the form values submitting to model, ActionResult needs to create barcode from model, refresh the same page and It will show only barcodeImage to me.

How can I configure it ?

Best regards.

Comment: It seems to me like you need to double check your code